# how to Output date as 10-Dec-15?

Tags: shell

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")  #displayed as 2015-12-10
DAY=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")  #displayed as 10-Dec-2015
DAY1=$(date +"%d-%b")    #displayed as 10-Dec
```

how to Output  date as 10-Dec-15?

Comment: You can look here for all the available date format: [linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a small `y` which gives the short year as opposed to `Y` which gives the long year.

```
DAY=$(date +"%d-%b-%y")
```